# Is there a specific solution for file permission issues?

Tags: joomla2.5, file-permissions

I am doing a website(Joomla) and I am using admiror gallery. Everything is working fine while I was working in the localhost but now that I migrated it to a live server, I am having problems in uploading images in the gallery.

The first is when I create a new folder to contain my new images. When I create it and try to upload a zip file, it's taking forever to load only to find out that it's not even uploading at all. When I looked into it, the reason is when a new folder is created, the permission is 755 by default, thus, making changes on the folder is not allowed. I need to change the file permission to 777 and now I am able to upload my images but there is another problem that occurs. The thumbnails in the backend are showing broken images. This is because the 'thumbs' directory in home/administrator/components/com_admirorgallery/assets/thumbs/ is again set to 755. I tried to change it to 777 and reupload the images again. The images gets uploaded but the problem with the thumbnails is still there. I checked again the folder and the permission is reverted back to 755.

Is there something I can do with this? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try Admin Tools from AkeebaBackup.com which has a nice little feature of fixing file permissions throughout the site. Link: https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/admin-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

You should check the files and folder owner, not only permission.
PHP user (Joomla) is the creator of thumb folder, thus it should be able to create files in that directory. Also, it is not safe to have 777 on live site.

Shambhala made a suggestion that should help. Also you should use AkeebaBackup when migrating from local to live server, I never had problems with it.